Why is there Heap Fetch even though i have index covering all column in the selection?
Table
create table students (
id serial primary key, 
 g int,
 firstname text, 
lastname text, 
middlename text,
address text,
 bio text,
dob date,
id1 int,
id2 int,
id3 int,
id4 int,
id5 int,
id6 int,
id7 int,
id8 int,
id9 int
);


insert into students (g,
firstname, 
lastname, 
middlename,
address ,
 bio,
dob,
id1 ,
id2,
id3,
id4,
id5,
id6,
id7,
id8,
id9) 
select 
random()*100,
substring(md5(random()::text ),0,floor(random()*31)::int),
substring(md5(random()::text ),0,floor(random()*31)::int),
substring(md5(random()::text ),0,floor(random()*31)::int),
substring(md5(random()::text ),0,floor(random()*31)::int),
substring(md5(random()::text ),0,floor(random()*31)::int),
now(),
random()*100000,
random()*100000,
random()*100000,
random()*100000,
random()*100000,
random()*100000,
random()*100000,
random()*100000,
random()*100000
 from generate_series(0, 50000000);

i populated like 20 Million rows.
Now i created covering index.
create index stu_g_idx on students(g) include (id);
Did  vacuum (analyze, verbose, full); Even after that why postgres query still hitting heap ?
explain (analyze, buffers)
select id
from students
where g > 14 and g < 95
order by g desc
limit 1;

Results in:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..0.56 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.049..0.050 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4
   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using s_g_idx on students  (cost=0.43..606253.57 rows=4799436 width=8) (actual time=0.046..0.047 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((g > 14) AND (g < 95))
         Heap Fetches: 1
         Buffers: shared hit=4
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=89 read=10 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 1.275 ms
 Execution Time: 0.102 ms
(10 rows)

Can someone explain why is that ? I'm trying to learn the internals.

Index Only Scan, it's only using the index, not the table. And pretty fast, 0.1ms to execute.

@FrankHeikens  Thank you, but my question why is there Heap Fetch ?

Good question. Maybe @LaurezAlbe can have some insight on this.

It could be because of the visibility: An index-only scan, after finding a candidate index entry, checks the visibility map bit for the corresponding heap page.. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html

@FrankHeikens I changed to LIMIT 100 fiddle and the plan shows 100 fetches. Seems like it checks for every row.

PostgreSQL always reads the table for visibility. Vaccuum (not vaccuum full) updates the visibility map to avoid going to all rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/Qel7Uab6
Doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-VISIBILITY-MAP
